How to use would in right manner?
I'm confused on the usage of would in sentences. I've seen people using it in future sentence like, I would meet you soon or I would do it for you. Is it correct usage of would? Kindly correct me on this.

"I would do it for you" is fine (although it might not mean what you think it means), "I would meet you soon" sounds a bit odd but could be used in some contexts ("I would meet you soon but..."). Would has various meanings and you should start by looking in a textbook, dictionary, or grammar (such as this), to appreciate the ways it can be used. Without knowing what you want to say, it's hard to be more specific.

This question is similar to: Is it ok to use "would" for future reference?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Using 'would'
Using "would" for future tense can sometimes be a bit confusing because "would" is typically used to express conditional situations or polite requests, rather than simple future actions. However, in some cases, "would" can be used to refer to future actions in a more hypothetical or uncertain way.
"I will go" typically indicates a definite future action. For example, if you say, "I will go to the store tomorrow," it means you have made a decision or a plan to go to the store in the future.
"I would go," on the other hand, can have a few different meanings depending on the context:
Polite Request: "I would go if you asked me." This can be a polite way to offer to do something in the future, or to express willingness to do something if a condition is met.
Hypothetical or Uncertain Future Action: "I would go to the party if I had time." This suggests a hypothetical future action, indicating that you might go to the party if certain conditions were met (in this case, having enough time).
Past Habit: "When I was younger, I would go to the beach every weekend." In this case, "would" is used to describe a past habitual action, rather than a future action.
In summary, "I will go" is typically used to express a definite future action, while "I would go" can have different meanings depending on the context, such as expressing a polite request, a hypothetical or uncertain future action, or a past habitual action.
( Above answer from Quora ) https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-use-would-for-future-tense-means-I-will-go-vs-I-would-go-what-are-meaning-of-these-two-sentences)
'would' usage in detail
Technically, would is the past tense of will, but it is an auxiliary verb that has many uses, some of which even express the present tense. It can be used in the following ways:
To ask questions:
Would you like some coleslaw? = Do you want some coleslaw?
Would you turn in your assignment now? = Please turn in your assignment now.
With who, what, when, where, why, how:
How would the neighbors react?
What would you do if I sang out of tune?
In the two sentences above, would means about the same thing as will.
To make polite requests:
I would like more coleslaw, please. = I want more coleslaw, please.
I would like you to sit down now. = I want you to sit down now.
To show a different response if the past had been different:
I would have helped you if I had known you were stranded.
(I didn't know that you were stranded. This "not knowing" occurred before my not helping you.)
John would've missed the trail if Mary hadn't waited for him at the stream.
(First Mary waited for him. If her response had been to not wait, then next John would have been on the wrong trail.)
To tone down strong, controversial statements-not recommended in formal essays:
I would have to say that you're acting a bit immature.
Here would has a similar meaning to do but less emphatic.
To explain an outcome to a hypothetical situation:
Should I win a million dollars, I would fix up my house.
Think of should as if, and would as will.
To show habitual past action:
Helen would sob whenever John would leave home.
Think of would as did.
To show repetitive past action:
For a moment the plane would be airborne, then it would bump back down along the hard earth.
(The plane was in the air and then back on the ground several times.)
To show preference between two choices, used with rather or sooner:
I would sooner die than face them. = I prefer death in place of facing them.
I would rather handwrite than type. = I prefer handwriting instead in typing.
However, the second choice may by implied but not stated:
I would rather die.
Implied is that I would rather die than...do whatever it is that the context has provided as an alternative to dying.
To show wish or desire:
Those people would allow gambling. = Those people want to allow gambling.
Would it were so. = I wish it were so. (Infrequently used)
We wish that he would go. = We want him to go.
To show intention or plan:
She said she would come. = She said she was planning to come.
To show choice:
I would put off the test if I could.
This means my choice is to delay taking the test, but I do not have the ability to delay taking it.
To express doubt:
The answer would seem to be correct. = The answer is probably correct.
To show future likelihoods relative to past action:
He calculated that he would get to the camp around 6 p.m. The men would have dinner ready for him.
The first sentence means he believed his camp arrival time was going to be about 6:00 p.m. The "calculating" (or believing) happened in the past, yet the arrival is going to occur later. The second sentence predicts that, at that future time, dinner will be ready for him.
Strange but true: Notice how changing have to had can change the way would works:
Would you had changed your mind. = I wish you had changed your mind.
Would you have changed your mind. = If circumstances had been different, is it possible that you might have changed your mind?
https://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/would.html#:~:text=Technically%2C%20would%20is%20the%20past,even%20express%20the%20present%20tense.
